# Crawling a website , Proxy function issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am crawling a educational website. I want to insert college and course details

There is link to next page:

```
<a onclick="SetCourseID('20232')">PGDCA</a>
```

This javascript function send AJAX request to :

```
url/ajax.php?CourseID=20232
```

It set `CourseId Session` and redirect to page:

```
url/CollegeName
```

Course will be loaded as per CourseID stored in session
How to set Session in `ajax.php` from `C# code`.

Or How can i solve this proble??
How to call javascript function form Server???

Comment: Explain better please. You are crawling a PHP website using ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set sessions in c# for PHP. The URL you mentioned looks like PHP is getting the information through the URL and not a session or cookie set. Which is a good thing.

Set your crawler to parse all the url's to get the course ID's

Then have the crawler crawl /url/ajax.php?courseid={insert id you parsed out}

Then save the resultset of the 2nd crawl

Answer (score 0):

client side

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function yourFunction() {
        alert("hi");

    }

</script>
```

server side(u can calling this client side function from server like this)

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myScript", "yourFunction();", true);
```